# Тема для Yii2, checkbox, dropDownList

Tags: html, css, yii2, checkbox, themes

Добрый день. Скачал я для yii2 эту тему: http://yii2.themefactory.net/theme/53/tf-dorian , установил, работает. Но есть несколько нюансов. Есть у меня таблица с чекбоксами и вот после установки темы чекбоксы пропали. В чем причина, я нашел - у темы есть кастомные чекбоксы и стандартные просто скрыли `position: absolute; left: -9999px;` вот так. Но появился ворос, как их вывести (кастомные) ? Погуглив я сделал так:

```
<table width="30%">
    <tr>
        <th>
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onclick="toggle(this);"/><br/>
            <label for="checkbox">Check all</label>
        </th>
        <th>Name:</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($poll as $item): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><input type=checkbox name="user_id[<?= $item->id ?>]" value=1 checked="checked"></td>
            <td><?= $item->username ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

Добавил `<label>`, но проблему это не решило. Вот часть кода для чекбоксов из темы:

```css
/***************
   Checkboxes
***************/
/* CUSTOM CSS CHECKBOXES */
form p {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  text-align: left; }

form p:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px; }

/* Remove default checkbox */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked), [type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}

[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label, [type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  /* webkit (safari, chrome) browsers */
  -moz-user-select: none;
  /* mozilla browsers */
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  /* webkit (konqueror) browsers */
  -ms-user-select: none;
  /* IE10+ */ }

/* checkbox aspect */
[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 2px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
  -moz-border-radius: 1px;
  border-radius: 1px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s; }

/* Unchecked styles */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before {
  top: 0px;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 2px solid #5a5a5a; }

/* Checked styles */
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  left: -3px;
  top: -4px;
  width: 12px;
  height: 22px;
  border-top: 2px solid transparent;
  border-left: 2px solid transparent;
  border-right: 2px solid #0f9d58;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #0f9d58;
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(40deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(40deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateZ(40deg);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(40deg);
  transform: rotateZ(40deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -moz-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -ms-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  -o-transform-origin: 100% 100%;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%; }

/* disabled checkbox */
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before, [type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  box-shadow: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
  -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotateZ(0deg);
  transform: rotateZ(0deg); }

[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26); }

[type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:hover:before {
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26); }

.switch, .switch * {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none; }

.switch label {
  cursor: pointer; }

.switch label input[type=checkbox]:first-child {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0; }

.switch label input[type=checkbox]:first-child:checked + .lever {
  background-color: #7bc5be; }

.switch label input[type=checkbox]:first-child:checked + .lever:after {
  background-color: #009587; }

.switch label .lever, .switch label input[type=checkbox][disabled]:first-child + .lever {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #818181;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition: background 0.3s ease;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 5px; }

.switch label .lever:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #F1F1F1;
  border-radius: 20px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  left: -5px;
  top: -2px;
  transition: left 0.3s ease, background 0.3s ease, box-shadow 0.1s ease; }

.switch label input[type=checkbox][disabled]:first-child + .lever:after, .switch label input[type=checkbox][disabled]:checked:first-child + .lever:after {
  background-color: #BDBDBD; }

input[type=checkbox]:first-child:checked ~ .lever:active:after {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 0 0 15px rgba(0, 149, 135, 0.1); }

input[type=checkbox]:first-child ~ .lever:active:after, input[type=checkbox][disabled]:first-child ~ .lever:active:after {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 0 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); }

.switch label input[type=checkbox]:first-child:checked + .lever:after {
  left: 30px; }
```

И еще есть dropDownList который не отображается, наверное по той же причине что и чекбоксы. Отображается только его hint.(UPD) - да, для dropdown стоит `display: none` и тоже есть код.
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такими делами ?

Comment: `materialize.js` подключён? Поизучай эту страничку: http://materializecss.com/forms.html

Comment: @Blacknife да, подключен. `<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo $this->theme->baseUrl ?>/js/materialize.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @Blacknife а по вашей ссылке там используют лейблы, как и сделал. Но вот не ясно откуда взять id для чекбокса что бы его в лейбл написать.